# Oracle ODP.NET and double clicking hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, session, odp.net, session-state

I've installed ODP.NET and am using the session state service through Oracle for an ASP.NET website.  I tested it, I thought, pretty thoroughly and didn't see any major problems.  Some of the users have been complaining of exception errors however when they use the system.  I added some extra logging and found out how to reproduce the issue.  It happens when a user double clicks on a hyperlink.  I have never thought about double clicking a hyperlink before in my life and never knew that users like doing that, so I hadn't tested that possibility.   This sends 2 identical requests to save a session item, with the same primary key.  I'm using ODP.NET 11.1.0 for the .NET 2.0 framework, and the functions being called have been obfuscated by Oracle, so I can't fix it there.  Has anyone else had this problem?  Does anyone know of a solution, other than to tell the users that you don't double click hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, This sounds like something Oracle should address.  Their code should be checking for this and preventing it.

You may have to put a check into your hyperlink handlers to prevent the double-submission.  You could use a utility class as a wrapper around the Oracle session provider with some `lock` statements to prevent double submission.  I'd be careful, however- you could introduce performance problems.